# Concatenation of matrices

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I could not find anywhere my problem: I wanna write in LateX the following drawing.
It is a matrix made of submatrices, which elements contains the elements of near matrices
[image: 1]

Had fun writing the description.
Thanks a lot,
Davide

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) it is common practice to (try to) provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.
Questions posting just an image sounds a lot like "please do it for me"

Comment: Yeah, I tried it but the best I could do was to obtain a normal matrix with some inside. Sorry!

Answer (score 11):

Welcome! Just make the distance between the rows negative.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\[\begingroup\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  [ & &]& & & \\[-1.4ex]
   & [&&] & & \\[-1.4ex]
   & &[& &] & \\
   & & & & & \ddots\\
 \end{bmatrix}\endgroup
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

You can make TeX do the computations.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{b}{n}{<->cmexb10}{}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{cmex}{b}{n}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\,
\hbox{\boldmath\valign{%
  #\cr
  \hbox{$\!\Big[$}\vfill\cr\noalign{\quad}
  \vfill\hbox{$\!\Big[$}\vfill\cr\noalign{\quad}
  \hbox{$\Big]\!$}\vspace{2pt}\hbox{$\!\Big[$}\cr\noalign{\quad}
  \vfill\hbox{$\Big]\!$}\vfill\cr\noalign{\quad}
  \vfill\hbox{$\Big]\!$}\cr
}}
\\
&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Apart from `\valign`, the trick is to notice that the brackets are placed symmetrically in their bounding box, but happily the “blank” part turns out to be `3mu`, so it can be removed with `\!`.

Another trick is to enable bold large symbols.

[image]